# Validity of equation for $E \times B$ drift in SI and Gaussian unit systems

Tags: electromagnetism, units, plasma-physics, si-units, solar-wind

I derive $E \times B$ drift $\vec v_{E \times B} = \dfrac{\vec E \times \vec B}{B^2}$ and in SI I use V/m and T for the fields. I do not use Gaussian (cgs) units often, but I thought this equation holds for cgs. However, the conversion factors for statvolt/cm and gauss are $1/3 \times 10^2$ and $10^4$, so one gets additional 1/3 factor. Is it really there in cgs equation for the drift or do I miss something?

Comment: Quick conversion:  |E| = |VxB| ~ $10^{-3} \ \lvert V \rvert \ \lvert V \rvert$ mV/m (if V is in km/s and B in nT).  So a 400 km/s flow speed and 10 nT magnetic field give E ~ 4 mV/m.  Then we can recover 400 km/s by seeing that if E is orthogonal to B, we have u ~ E/B = $4 \times 10^{-3}/\left( 10 \times 10^{-9} \right)$ m/s = 400 km/s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation for $\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B}$ drift in Gaussian units is
$$
\mathbf{u} = c \frac{\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B}}{B^2};
$$
see, for example, Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics*, 3rd ed.  Also, your conversion for the electric field is incorrect;  it should be $$1 \text{ V/m} = \frac{1}{\text{"3"}} \times 10^{-4} \text{ statvolt/cm}$$
(again, see Jackson, and note that "3" = 2.99792458.)

Taking into the correct conversions into account, and noting that the SI result will be in m/s while the Gaussian result will be in cm/s, resolves the discrepancy.